# RegEx for excluding substrings in URLs

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm working in setting up Hotjar recordings for a subdomain at our business. However i'm having issues excluding the substrings of this subdomain because the subdomain is not a fixed string.

Basically the subdomain is a category page. In total we have about 34 different categories and i wish to record all these categories since they are basically the same page with only changes in some copy.

Example category urls:

```
https://se.readly.com/products/magazines/se/celebrities_entertainment
https://se.readly.com/products/magazines/se/dagstidningar
```

Example of substrings urls of category pages:

```
https://se.readly.com/products/magazines/se/dagstidningar/kvaellsposten-1
https://se.readly.com/products/magazines/se/wedding/sisters-in-law-ett-nytt-slags-broellopsmagasin
https://se.readly.com/products/magazines/se/wedding/allt-om-broellop
```

Example of code i've tried without success (obviously):

```
\bse.readly.com/products/magazines/se/[a-z-_]+$
```

Comment: You want the first fixed part (https://se.readly.com/products/magazines/se/) or last unfixed part (dagstidningar/kvaellsposten-1)?

Comment: Do you mean like `^https?://\bse\.readly\.com/products/magazines/se/([a-z_-]+)` https://regex101.com/r/QhHzhI/1

Answer (score 0):

Here, we can step by step match the desired URLs. We might want to use capturing groups just to be easy to get the URLs components, if desired. Let's maybe start with something similar to:

```
^(.+?)(se.readly.com)(\/products\/magazines\/se\/)([a-z0-9-_]+)(\/[a-z0-9-_]+)$
```

and we can reduce the boundaries that we have if we want to.

[image]

### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/PEfC0S/1/)